# regex for parsing dimension measurement descriptions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nlp, data-science

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

(Reputation too low to post images, sorry)

Essentially, for rows whose `work_height`, `work_width`, `work_depth` dimensions are missing but there's a description of those dimensions in the `work_dimensions` column, I want to parse the said description into the `work_height`, `work_width`, `work_depth` columns. There are a few types of structures available based on my exploration:

- __ unit x __ unit x __ unit. This one should be easy.
- __ unit x __ unit \newline __ unit x __ unit, I believe these are two different image dimension settings possible for the same image. I want to create a new image item (row) with the second setting (or third or whatever).
- The written out mixed fractions, e.g. `16 7/8 in (42.8 cm)`. How is this supposed to be parsed? This is one of the hard ones. Since the unit column `work_measurement_unit` is generally mm, that's the unit to parse I presume (and even then I have to convert from cm to mm).
- Measurement Description, followed by the mixed fraction and other unit in parentheses above, i.e. `Diameter: 19 3/7 in (72.5 cm)`.

If I can learn these cases I will probably have no issue with any other case that could come up, so any help would be appreciated?

I've only been able to come up with a solution for the first type of structure listed above.

To access the df above I used:

```py
mask = (df['work_dimensions'] != '-1') & (df['work_dimensions'].notnull()) & ((df[['work_height','work_width','work_depth']] == -1.0).sum(axis=1) == 3)

df[['work_dimensions','work_height','work_width','work_depth','work_measurement_unit']][mask]
```

I don't see anything wrong with the results yet but I could be missing stuff.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.... [You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1):

Update: I found a Github package to do my bidding, for those interested in parsing unit stuff.

[quantulum3](https://pypi.org/project/quantulum3/)

Comment: That is not an answer. SO isn't a discussion forum.