How to pull width & height out of string?
Our product table stores width & height directly in the product description.
I'm trying to break out width & height into their own separate numeric columns, so we don't have to try and mess with long strings every time we need size data.
However, the issue I'm running into is that these descriptions aren't standardized. Most sizes are correctly stored as W" X H", but some can also be W"XH", -W"xH"-, and some can even have a third double quote for corner rounding, length, etc.
Is it possible to create a one-size-fits-all function that can pull width & height out of all types of description formats? Should I break them down into separate functions for each format?
Constants:

All widths & heights are whole numbers
All widths & heights are directly followed by a double quote
There is an "X" between all widths & heights

Variables:

Spacing & surrounding characters (not always a blank space before/after dimensions)
Number of double quotes can be more than 2.
Can be either 1, 2, or 3 digit numbers (1" X 1", 10" X 1", 100" X 1", etc.)

Sample Data:



Product
Description
Expected Width
Expected Height




1000
HIP .100 12" X 18" Sign Digital
12
18


1001
HIP-080-36"X72"-Simple Sign-RS
36
72


1002
DG3 .080 21" x 21" Sign 3" R
21
21


1003
HIP-080-36"X72"-Simple Sign-RS
36
72


1004
DG3 FLO-125-100"x80"-Hand Applied
100
80


1005
DG3 FLUOR Dbl .080 30" X 30" X 30" Yield
30
30



What I've tried:
SELECT
    UPPER(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            RIGHT(
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1), 
            LEN(
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1)
                ) 
            - CHARINDEX('"', 
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1)
            ) + 3)
        , '"', '')
    , ' ','')) AS Result, Description

FROM HQMT
WHERE UPPER(Description) LIKE '%"%X%"%'

Result:



Result
Description




12X18
HIP .100 12" X 18" Sign Digital


36X72
HIP-080-36"X72"-Simple Sign-RS


21X21
DG3 .080 21" x 21" Sign 3" R


36X72
HIP-080-36"X72"-Simple Sign-RS


00X80
DG3 FLO-125-100"x80"-Hand Applied


30X30
DG3 FLUOR Dbl .080 30" X 30" X 30" Yield



With these results, I plan to pull all characters left of the "X" for width and all characters right of the "X" for height. This is mostly correct, but 3 digit widths are getting cut off. Any ideas on how to fix / make more dynamic?

Honestly, this is unlikely to be a task for SQL Server, and a language with strong string manipulation tools would be a better choice. Of course, the real solution is fix the data; this needs some significant normalisation.

How do you want to handle descriptions that have single or double quotes that are not related to dimensions?  Such as "Big Bertha" Sign 96"x120"   or strings with X  such as model 2000 Xavier 3 sign

This is a hard task even for languages with robust parsing tools. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296129/regex-for-parsing-dimension-measurement-descriptions

@BartMcEndree Luckily those don't exist, quotes are only used for dimensions in this table. Strings with an X and no quotes are already being filtered out by WHERE UPPER(Description) LIKE '%"%X%"%'.

Even if I can get 80% of them updated through this function, I can manually key in the rest. This will only be a one-time update and will not be a problem in the future.

Maybe grab 4 chrs left and right of the X and remove all non numeric chrs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625548/select-query-to-remove-non-numeric-characters

my thoughts go to REGULAR EXPRESSIONS....

Use TRANSLATE to remove all chars except numbers and X (applied to 4 chars preceeding ")
SELECT
    UPPER(
     REPLACE(TRANSLATE(
            RIGHT(
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1), 
            LEN(
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1)
                ) 
            - CHARINDEX('"', 
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1)
            ) + 4)
            , 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz+()- ,#+"', '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'), '@', '')  
         ) 
  AS Result, Description

FROM HQMT
WHERE UPPER(Description) LIKE '%"%X%"%'

fiddle

This is close, thank you! I had to change all the translate characters to uppercase though, and modify each Description reference to UPPER(Description). Without doing that, it was only replacing lowercase. It also breaks if the 4th preceding character is a number (HIP .125 6" X 12" comes out as 56X12). I just manually excluded those records for now.

Make sure you put that into a user defined function so that everyone can use it :-)

--Grab 4 chrs preceeding " and Adding another replace to remove dash
SELECT
    UPPER(
     REPLACE( 
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            RIGHT(
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1), 
            LEN(
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1)
                ) 
            - CHARINDEX('"', 
                LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description,CHARINDEX('"',Description)+1)-1)
            ) + 4)
        , '"', '')
    , ' ','')
    ,'-','')
              ) AS Result, Description

FROM HQMT
WHERE UPPER(Description) LIKE '%"%X%"%'

fiddle



Result
Description




12X18
HIP .100 12" X 18" Sign Digital


36X72
HIP-080-36"X72"-Simple Sign-RS


21X21
DG3 .080 21" x 21" Sign 3" R


36X72
HIP-080-36"X72"-Simple Sign-RS


100X80
DG3 FLO-125-100"x80"-Hand Applied


30X30
DG3 FLUOR Dbl .080 30" X 30" X 30" Yield




This just inserts enough spaces around X and - characters so that you can safely grab the last three characters preceding each quote mark:
select * from T cross apply (
    select
        min(case when ordinal = 1 then cast(ltrim(right(value, 3)) as int) end),
        min(case when ordinal = 2 then cast(ltrim(right(value, 3)) as int) end)
    from string_split(
             replace(replace(replace(Description, '-', ' '), 'X', ' '), ' ', '   '),
             '"', 1) as s
) as dimensions(width, height)

This assumes width and height always appear adjacent to the first two quote marks without a space and that you're using a newer edition of SQL Server with the ordinal output from string_split(). That case could be handled but as it exists that would cause an error.
https://dbfiddle.uk/yfi5b4Tl
